# Change Assembly Version in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a C# Application and want the version of assembly to be:
01.02.03.123

I have changed the following value in AssemblyInfo.cs

[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("01.02.03.123")]

But, when I Build the project, and see the File Version of my assembly it shows as
1.2.3.123

How can I get "01.02.03.123" as the version.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Leading zeros are ignored. BTW: Why do you want this non-standard format?

Comment: What you want is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Each portion of the assembly version is stored as a 16-bit integer, so no, it's not possible to start those numbers with leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

```
Version.Major.ToString("00") + "." + Version.Minor.ToString("00") + "." + Version.Build.ToString("00") + "." + Version.Revision.ToString("00");
```

Comment: Nice job finding a way to produce the result the OP was looking for!